# How to add group ID by same rows?

Tags: r

Suppose I have:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]), c(1, 2, 3)))

df:
  x
1 A
2 B
3 B
4 C
5 C
6 C
```

How can I add another column (group ID) based on the same letter on `df$x`:

```
  x group
1 A 1
2 B 2
3 B 2
4 C 3
5 C 3
6 C 3
```

Thanks!

**-------------EDIT--------------**

Sorry, guess I should rephrase my question. Here we have:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]), c(1, 2, 3)),
                 y = rep(as.factor(LETTERS[3:1]), c(3, 2, 1)))

df
  x y
1 A C
2 B C
3 B C
4 C B
5 C B
6 C A
```

And I need a column of group ID to separate x & y pairs:

```
df
  x y group
1 A C 1
2 B C 2
3 B C 2
4 C B 3
5 C B 3
6 C A 4
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does there have to be a specified mapping, like A=1, B=2, C=3? Or does it just need to be integers starting from 1 such that each integer uniquely maps to a group (that was my assumption in the answer)?

Comment: Yes. Actually the first column are some location names: US, CA, AU and I need to add a group ID to different locations. No specific mapping constraint.

Comment: I think you meant for rows 4 and 5 to have the same group, no?

Comment: See edits- I think it's just what you want

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Yes. Corrected the typos. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
df$group = df$x:df$y
#  x y group
#1 A C   A:C
#2 B C   B:C
#3 B C   B:C
#4 C B   C:B
#5 C B   C:B
#6 C A   C:A
```

`group` in this case is a factor. If you want it to have numeric IDs:

```
df$group = as.numeric(df$x:df$y)
#  x y group
#1 A C     3
#2 B C     6
#3 B C     6
#4 C B     8
#5 C B     8
#6 C A     7
```

ETA: If you want the group IDs to be consecutive integers:

```
df$group = match(df$x:df$y, unique(df$x:df$y))
#  x y group
#1 A C     1
#2 B C     2
#3 B C     2
#4 C B     3
#5 C B     3
#6 C A     4
```

Comment: No, actually the first column are some location names: US, CA, AU and I need to add a group ID to different locations.

Comment: If there is a one to one mapping between the locations and the group ID then this column is redundant.

Comment: Does the above do what you want?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Sorry for the confusion. Looks like I do need a group column to separate a pair of two other columns. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Great! Just what I want. Thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
df$group <- as.numeric(factor(with(df, paste(x,y))))
```

...very similar to the other solution.